# Acumatica: How to override Bill-To Address and Ship-To Address in Sales Order using the REST API

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am doing an integration with Acumatica.
In my SalesOrder request, I am creating a Sales Order with Bill-To Address and Ship-To Address.
After the request was made I have check in acumatica Sales Order that the Sales Order do not have the Bill-To and Ship-To Address as specified in my request.

It seems that it is using the Default Address that was set in the CustomerID
[image]

Comment: Can you share some request samples that you have tried? It will help assess the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample API which shows how to override the Ship-To address.  Pay attention to the ShipTo entity declared

```
{
"OrderNbr": {
    "value": "37631"
},
"OrderType": {
    "value": "SO"
},
"Date": {
    "value": "12/18/20 2:21:10 PM"
},
"note": "     ",
"CustomerID": {
    "value": "ABC123"
},
"ExternalRef": {
    "value": "37631"
},
"Description": {
    "value": "Self Import"
},
"CustomerOrder": {
    "value": "                    "
},
"Processed": {
    "value": false
},
"ShippingSettings": {
    "Priority": {
        "value": 2
    },
    "ShipVia": {
        "value": "2ND_DAY"
    }
},
"ShipToContactOverride": {
    "value": true
},
  "ShipToContact": {
    "BusinessName": {
        "value": "Bob Jones"
    },
    "Attention": {
        "value": ""
    },
    "Phone1": {
        "value": ""
    },
    "Email": {
        "value": ""
    }
    },
"ShipToAddressOverride": {
    "value": true
},
"ShipToAddress": {
    "AddressLine1": {
        "value": "123 Main Street"
    },
    "AddressLine2": {
        "value": ""
    },
    "AddressLine3": {
        "value": ""
    },
    "City": {
        "value": "Ft. Smith"
    },
    "State": {
        "value": "AR"
    },
    "PostalCode": {
        "value": "72913"
    }
},
"Details": [
    {
        "InventoryID": {
            "value": "7239-1"
        },
        "OrderQty": {
            "value": 2
        },
        "UnitPrice": {
            "value": 35.07
        }
    },
    {
        "InventoryID": {
            "value": "7543"
        },
        "OrderQty": {
            "value": 2
        },
        "UnitPrice": {
            "value": 436.98
        }
    },
    {
        "InventoryID": {
            "value": "6243-2"
        },
        "OrderQty": {
            "value": 8
        },
        "UnitPrice": {
            "value": 5.43
        }
    }
]
```

}